# What is `browser.call()` for in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, protractor

I've recently being going through the [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api) and noticed the [`browser.call()` method](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.call):

> Schedules a command to execute a custom function within the context of webdriver's control flow.

I would like to add this function to my toolkit, but I am not sure I completely understand when might it be used in practice and what use cases does it cover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way protractor works is it has an internal queue where it sets the order of your functions. So if you were to call a function somewhere in your test without telling protractor, that function would be outside the queue and the actual execution of the function could happen anytime.
You can check that using `console.log("something")` inside your tests and see that they don't execute in the order the application is written.

If you want a function to run specifically after a webdriver event (meaning you want to add it to the queue) you can call it inside the `browser.call()` like this

```
browser.previousStep();
browser.call(functionX, this, parameters...)
browser.nextStep()
```

The `this` parameter represents:

> The object in whose scope to execute the function (i.e. the `this`
>   object for the function).

as stated in the documentation.