# Protractor: Timing of .spec and .po.ts file execution?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

Newbie question on TypeScript and Protractor:

I have two simple helper functions that reside in a shared.po.ts file in my Protractor suite. They are called by the third **it()** in my .spec file - that is, they are not called immediately on Protractor test execution:

```
formattedDate(){
  var MyDate = new Date();
  var mth = ('0' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1));
  var day = ('0' + MyDate.getDate());
  var yr = MyDate.getFullYear();   
  return mth.slice(-2) +'/' + day.slice(-2) +'/' + yr;}

formattedDateTime(){
  var MyDate = new Date();      
  var hrs = ('0' + MyDate.getHours()).slice(-2); 
  var mins =('0' + MyDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
  var time = hrs +':'+mins;
  return this.formattedDate() + ' ' +  time;}
```

I call the function formattedDateTime() like so in my .spec file:

```
  let formattedDateTime = shared.formattedDate();     
  console.log(formattedDateTime);
```

When I execute my test scripts, I immediately get a console item "03/15/2019 10:15". I am not running headless tests: I can see a browser window executing my scripts, and it is clearly visible that the section of the .spec file that calls formattedDateTime() has not executed yet.

Can someone explain how this might be happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is designed to work with asynchronous calls that return promises. These get added to an internal queue and executed in what seems like a synchronous manner. Because `console.log` is a synchronous call, it runs outside of this queue and therefore seems to execute out of order. Try something like this instead:

```
browser.call(() => { console.log(formattedDateTime); });
```

This is a pretty important concept to understand when writing Protractor tests; I'd suggest doing some reading up on control flow in Protractor. There's also a similar SO question you might find helpful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955929/what-is-browser-call-for-in-protractor).